# Printing few strings in one print command differs from printing them using multiple print commands

Tags: python, string, output

Why calling the first print results in different output than calling next four? What is happening here?

```
crates = 5
gap = 10

print(crates * ' ', crates * '#', gap * ' ', crates * '#')

print("differs from:")

print(crates * ' ', end = '')
print(crates * '#', end = '')
print(gap * ' ', end = '')
print(crates * '#')
```

Comment: `print` adds a space between things it prints (i.e. each `,` adds a space to the `print`). Do `end=' '` instead of `end=''` and they will match. Or add `sep=''` to the end of your first print.

Comment: Hi @user3565923 I have tried to break down why the two cases have the print pattern you see, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.

In the first case, printing multiple strings separated by a comma in `print` adds an explicit space `' '` between them, which happens because of the default argument `sep=' '` of print which separates multiple items being printed by a whitespace

```
In [124]: print('hello','world')                                                                                                                             
hello world
```

In the second case, putting `end = ''` ensures that there is line is not terminated by a newline `\n`, (as per the default argument `end='\n'`), but by an empty character

```
In [130]: print('hello',end='') 
     ...: print('world',end='')                                                                                                                              
helloworld
```

Running your example in the question gives us

```
      #####            #####
differs from:
     #####          #####
```

Where you see an extra whitespace `' '` added in the first string, but not in the second string, and the second string not being terminated by a newline, but by an empty character